# iOS app freezes on incoming notification while composing post

Tags: bug, ios-app

I was composing an answer in the app when the UI locked up. I had to force-quit the app, losing my draft in progress.

There was an incoming message notification, which I assume was the trigger for the bug.

- App Version: 1.5.3.5
- Device: iPhone 5s (GSM)
- OS Version: Version 9.3.2 (Build 13F69)